# How to handle cypher query common stanzas

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm writing a bunch of queries in order to build a tree inside Neo4j, but in order to add different types of new data, I'm writing the same opening stanzas for each of my queries.

Example: I want to be able to add `Root(identifier=Root1)->A(identifier=1)->B(identifier=2)...` without modifying the trees pointed to by other roots.

All of my queries start off with

```
Match
    (root:`Root` {identifier=$identifier})
Create 
    (root)-[:`someRel`]->(a:`A` {identifier=$a_identifier})
```

Then some time passes and A needs a child:

```
Match 
    (root:`Root` {identifier=$identifier})
    -[:`someRel`]->
    (a:`A` {identifier=$a_identifier})
Create 
    (a)-[:`someOtherRel`]->(b:`B` {identifier=$b_identifier})
```

Then some other time passes and maybe B needs a child, and I have to use the same opening stanza to get to A and then add another one to get the correct B.

Is there some functionality that I'm missing that will allow me to not have to build up those opening stanzas every time I want to get to the correct B, (or C or D) or do I just need to do this using string concatenation?

String concatenation example: (python)

```
MATCH
  {ROOT_LOOKUP_STANZA},
  {A_LOOKUP_STANZA},
  {B_LOOKUP_STANZA},
CREATE
  (b)-[:`c_relationship`]->(c:`C` {...})
```

Some additional notes:

- Root Nodes have to be uniquely identified
- The rest of the nodes have to be uniquely identified with their parents.  So the following is valid:

`Root(root)->A(a)->B(b)
Root(root)->A(a1)->B(b)`

In this case B(b) references two different nodes because their parents are different.

Comment: Can you describe what uniquely identifies a node in the tree? If the node's label+identifier isn't enough, then is it the connection to a specific root that makes it unique? Do you really need to specify all the nodes in between the root and the node? Also, are there any other incoming relationships to a node that are not part of the tree structure? (in other words, can we identify the root by traversing incoming relationships up to the :Root node?)

Comment: The way it looks to me you don't need to repeat these stanzas, you only need to match the most recent / closest node.  Root, then the second time A, then the third time B, and so on.  You appear to have an identifier, so index that, and in the program that is generating this cypher, just keep track of the last identifier written, match to that, extend tree from there.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Updated to help explain

Comment: @FrobberOfBits I don't know that this will work based on what I just added to the original comment.  Or do you mean keeping track of the actual node id (the number assigned by neo4j)?  I didn't think that the Neo4J developers recommended that, but that may have been in the context of linking to separate databases and then maintaining those links.

Comment: Another question...is it possible to have paths to too different :B nodes (with the same identifier property) where all the nodes in the path up to the parent are exactly the same, but the relationships could vary? So for example, 2 distinct :B nodes with the same property, with all the same parents, but one has a :someRel relationship to its parent, while the other has :someOtherRel relationship to that same parent? That would add another complication to your requirements, as you would then need to take relationship types into account, not just nodes in the path.

Answer (score 0):

So your main problem is that children do not have unique ids, only the root nodes have unique ids. Neo4j does not have have any mechanic (yet) to carry the final context of one query into the start of another, and makes no guarantee that a nodes internal id will be the same between queries. So for your data as is, you must match the whole chain to be sure you match the correct node to append to. There are a few things you can do make this not necessary though.

**Add a UUID**

By adding a universally unique id to each node (, and indexing that property,) you will be able to match on that id with the guarantee that there are no collisions and it will be the same across queries. Any time using a nodes internal ID would be useful, that is a good sign you could use UUID's in your data. (Also helps if the data is mirrored to other databases)

**Store the path as a Unique ID**

It's possible you don't know the UUID assigned in Neo4j (because it's not in the source data), but in a tree you can create a unique ID in the format of `<parent-ID>_<index><sorted-labels><source-id>`. The idea here is that the parent is guaranteed to have a unique id, and you combine that id with the info that makes this child unique to that parent. This allows you do generate a deterministic unique ID. (Requires a tree data structure, with a unique root id) In most cases, you can probably leave the index part out (that is for cases of lists/arrays in the source data). In essence, you are storing the path from the root node to this node as the nodes unique id. (Again, you will want an index on this id)

**Batch the job**

If this is all part of just one job, another option is pool the changes you want to make, and generate one cypher that will do all of them while Neo4j already has everything fetched.